# Preseeding or fixing "Force UEFI installation" on Hyper-V installation?

Tags: system-installation, uefi

I'm attempting to build an Ubuntu packer template on Hyper-V as a Generation 2 virtual machine, which means setting up an unattended installation. Based off what I've gleaned from Chef's [Bento](https://github.com/chef/bento), most of the setup they're using seems to work on Hyper-V without a hitch.

Here's the exact boot command I'm using:

```
...
"boot_command": [
  "c<wait>",
  "linuxefi<wait>",
  " /install/vmlinuz<wait>",
  " auto<wait>",
  " console-setup/ask_detect=false<wait>",
  " console-setup/layoutcode=us<wait>",
  " console-setup/modelcode=pc105<wait>",
  " debconf/frontend=noninteractive<wait>",
  " debian-installer=en_US<wait>",
  " fb=false<wait>",
  " kbd-chooser/method=us<wait>",
  " keyboard-configuration/layout=USA<wait>",
  " keyboard-configuration/variant=USA<wait>",
  " locale=en_US<wait>",
  " netcfg/get_domain=vm<wait>",
  " netcfg/get_hostname=vagrant<wait>",
  " grub-installer/bootdev=/dev/sda<wait>",
  " preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/ubuntu-16.10/preseed.cfg<wait>",
  " -- <wait>",
  "<enter><wait>",
  "initrdefi<wait>",
  " /install/initrd.gz<wait>",
  "<enter><wait>",
  "boot<wait>",
  "<enter><wait>"
],
...
```

(I've tried both `linux` and `linuxefi`/`initrd` and `initrdefi` as the commands, both end up with the same results. Fedora required the `efi` variants, so I left it there for consistency.)

The actual preseed file is exactly the same as that provided by Bento.

However, I am running into an issue during the disk partitioning. The full dialog box is

> This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later.
>
> If you wish to install in EUFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation here.
>
> Force UEFI installation?

I'm pretty confused about this because, for one, the drive should be completely empty as it was created new via Hyper-V.

Is there a way to either preseed or set a boot option for this value as `true`, or even better, to configure the Hyper-V installation so that it doesn't appear at all?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me when I was working on a gen2 template
https://github.com/taliesins/packer-baseboxes/blob/master/hyperv-ubuntu-16.04.json